# Keycloak silent login using access token

Tags: reactjs, session, keycloak, session-cookies

I am trying to implement a feature where the user logs directly to our portal.

I am getting the user's access token and refresh using the admin's credentials.

I tried initiating the session in the following way:

```
keycloak.init({
       token: userInfo.access_token,
       refreshToken: userInfo.refresh_token,
       checkLoginIframe: false,
     }).then((authenticated) => {
       //  console.log('authenticated', authenticated, keycloak);
       this.setState({ keycloak });
       this.setState({ authenticated });
       if (authenticated) {
         keycloak.login({
           clientId: 'process.env.clientId',
           redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3003/',
           prompt: 'none',
           scope: 'openid profile',
         }).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
 }).catch(err => console.log('Error initiating keycloak', err));
```

Using the above code I was able to get the create a session and get authenticated, but not able to set the cookies and manage a session in the browser using the login function. It returns an error message "login_required".

Can anyone suggest how to proceed further in creating a session and setting cookies of keycloak using the keycloak-js adapter?